# How do I get the event listener to change my css background color using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to be able to change the background color of the list item.
When I remove the if-statement and just set the background color, it works.
However it fails with the if-statement.
I don't understand why it's not working. pls help.

```
HTML

<ul id="testList"> Test List
    <li id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="item2">Item 2</li>
</ul>


CSS

#testList {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 200px 0px 0px 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#testList li {
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#testList li:hover{cursor: pointer;}
#item1 {background-color: white;}


Javascript

var item1 = document.getElementById('item1');
function setColor(){
    if (item1.style.backgroundColor == 'white'){
        item1.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    } else if (item1.style.backgroundColor == 'green'){
        item1.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
}
item1.addEventListener('click', function(){setColor()}, false);
```

Comment: No, the 'grey' value is to do with the 'ul' not the 'li'. Also like I said at the top, I managed to change the color once when I removed the if-statement but it doesn't work with the if-statement for some reason. I tried what you mentioned anyway but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the initial value of background color on the item is not set. The item 1 has the background color white from the css styling on the id. But item1.style.backgroundColor will only return the value set directly on the element inline.

```js
var item1 = document.getElementById('item1');
function setColor(){
    if (!item1.style.backgroundColor || item1.style.backgroundColor == 'white'){
        item1.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    } else if (item1.style.backgroundColor == 'green'){
        item1.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
}
item1.addEventListener('click', function(){setColor()}, false);
```

```css
#testList {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 200px 0px 0px 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#testList li {
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#testList li:hover{cursor: pointer;}
#item1 {background-color: white;}
```

```html
   <ul id="testList"> Test List
    <li id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="item2">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow it worked. So this " !item1.style.backgroundColor | " was all I needed. After 2 hours lol. Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of doing such a swap:

You declare a class

```css
.background-green {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

Then you simply check if a certain element has this class. If it has, remove it. Otherwise add it.

```js
function switchBackground() {
    let el = document.getElementById("myElementId");
    if (el.classList.contains("background-green")) {
        el.classList.remove("background-green");
    }
    else {
        el.classList.add("background-green");
    }
}
```

This will make the element toggle between its default value and green. You can specify this default background color to be white in your CSS.

Comment: Noted. Thank you. Much appreciated.